# Unable to locate NamespaceHandler core

Tags: java, mule

```
org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Initialisation Failure: Configuration problem: Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace [http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/core/2.1]
Offending resource: URL [file:/D:/School/EAD/CourseSVN/bart/EA3/conf/dare2date-config.xml]
```

I know that you have to add stuff you need to mule's classpath, but how can it not handle the core?

My config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule
xmlns="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/core/2.1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/http/2.1"
xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/vm/2.1"
xmlns:stdio="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/stdio/2.1"
xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/cxf/2.1"
xmlns:mule-xml="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/xml/2.1"
xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/jms/2.1" 
xmlns:smtps="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/smtps/2.1"
xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/smtp/2.1"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/core/2.1 http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/core/2.1/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/stdio/2.1 http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/stdio/2.1/mule-stdio.xsd
    http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/vm/2.1 http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/vm/2.1/mule-vm.xsd
    http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/stdio/2.1 http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/stdio/2.1/mule-stdio.xsd
    http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/core/2.1 http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/core/2.1/mule.xsd 
    http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/xml/2.1 http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/xml/2.1/mule-xml.xsd
    http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/jms/2.1 http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/jms/2.1/mule-jms.xsd        
    http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/smtp/2.1 http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/smtp/2.1/mule-smtp.xsd
    http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/smtps/2.1 http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/smtps/2.1/mule-smtps.xsd      
    http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/cxf/2.1 http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/cxf/2.1/mule-cxf.xsd
">

...etc
```

Comment: Eddie, do you have mule-core.jar in your class path? How are you starting your esb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple, I did not have version 2.1 (but 2.2 or something).